# How to handle a 3 levels deep nested multi-step form in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, react-hooks, react-state

How do I handle the state, form data and logic of a nested multi step form which goes three levels deep because the input of a form field opens another entirely different set of questions/fields. I am new to react and all the tutorials I saw only handled three steps with only text fields and no radio buttons.

How exactly do I nest the steps while still maintaining the logic without making it all convoluted.

For context, the form I intend to build has a list of six global products from which you can only choose one.
These six global options have the same three subscription tiers. Subscription tier 1 has its set of form fields to bring up and so do subscription tier two and three.

Once you are in a subscription tier, there are three stages which consist of the product details, customer information and a final stage (which contains a page which lists all the filled form field and data the user filled in and also contains a button which goes to the payment page which is the last stage).

On each page that the application displays the current field to be filled, there is also a section that shows the previous field and the user data which the user can click to go back to edit that certain clicked field.

The page also contains two steppers which highlights each page's current question number in a stage and another stepper which highlights the current active stage among the overall stages( 1, 2, 3) since we only have three stages.

So if the user is on question 5 of stage 2. Number 5 will be highlighted on the question Number Stepper and 2 will also highlighted on the Stage Stepper. These steppers' numbers can be clicked only when they have been filled and that should take us to the exact field and data filled there to be edited. The user can always change stages and question number provided that they have only been filled.

I would really appreciate any guidance in the form of code architecture and/or explanation or a resource.

Here is an example of such tutorial reference point link that provided three steps: https://css-tricks.com/the-magic-of-react-based-multi-step-forms/

Thank you all

Answer (score 1):

Forms can get really tricky really quickly, unfortunately. And in my experience if you have a very complex set of data to capture using a form; you're going to need some really good abstractions and tools to deal with it.

The first thing to consider is if you can simplify the problem to allow yourself to create simpler forms. If you can for example keep your form more pure, meaning less interaction with the outside world, or keep how you do so in check you can try some simple abstractions. A favorite of mine is to use JavaScript generator to create a "saga" like syntax for sequential rendering.

Here's an example:

```js
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { Tale } from "../../react-tale";

const ChooseRocket = ({ launch }) => (
  <div>
    <p>Mission control here, what rocket are we launching today?</p>
    <button onClick={() => launch("red")}>Red Rocket</button>
    <button onClick={() => launch("green")}>Green Rocket</button>
    <button onClick={() => launch("blue")}>Blue Rocket</button>
  </div>
);

const CheckItem = ({ name, value, check }) => (
  <div>
    <input
      name={name}
      type="checkbox"
      value={value}
      onChange={(e) => check({ name, status: e.target.checked })}
    />
    <label htmlFor={name}>{name}</label>
  </div>
);

const CheckList = ({ list, check }) => (
  <div>
    <p>Lets run through safety procedures...</p>
    {list.map(({ name, status }) => (
      <CheckItem key={name} name={name} value={status} check={check} />
    ))}
  </div>
);

const GoNoGo = ({ go, nogo }) => (
  <div>
    <p>All checks ready, we have GO or NO-GO, what is your call?</p>
    <button onClick={nogo}>We are NO-GO</button>
    <button onClick={go}>We are a GO</button>
  </div>
);

function* launchProtocol() {
  const rocket = yield (next) => <ChooseRocket launch={next} />;

  let list = [
    { name: "BOOSTER", status: false },
    { name: "RETRO", status: false },
    { name: "FIDO", status: false },
  ];

  while (!list.every((check) => check.status)) {
    list = yield (next) => (
      <CheckList
        list={list}
        check={(x) => next(list.map((y) => (x.name === y.name ? x : y)))}
      />
    );
  }

  const going = yield (next) => (
    <GoNoGo go={() => next(true)} nogo={() => next(false)} />
  );

  if (going) {
    return `There goes the ${rocket} rocket!`;
  } else {
    return "Rescheduling launch to CTRL+R";
  }
}

const mount = document.getElementById("app");
if (mount) render(<Tale tale={launchProtocol} />, mount);
```

or something like this:

```js
import React from "react";
import { render, createPortal } from "react-dom";
import { Tale } from "../../react-tale";

const CallToAction = ({ onClick }) => (
  <div>
    Want to get in on something really cool?
    <button onClick={onClick}>Yes!</button>
  </div>
);

const Waiting = () => <div>Wainting for your answer!</div>;

const ConfirmationDialog = ({ yes, no }) => (
  <div>
    Are you sure about that?
    <button onClick={yes}>Yes!</button>
    <button onClick={no}>No</button>
  </div>
);

const Modal = ({ children }) =>
  createPortal(children, document.getElementById("modal"));

function* confirming() {
  yield (next) => <CallToAction onClick={next} />;

  const confirmation = yield (next) => (
    <div>
      <Waiting />
      <Modal>
        <ConfirmationDialog yes={() => next(true)} no={() => next(false)} />
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );

  if (confirmation) {
    return "Doing some cool stuff!";
  } else {
    yield (next) => (
      <div>
        That is okay, if you change your mind let me know.
        <button onClick={next}>I changed my mind!</button>
      </div>
    );
    yield* confirming();
  }
}

const mount = document.getElementById("app");
if (mount) render(<Tale tale={confirming} />, mount);
```

The `<Tale />` component is as follows:

```js
import { useMemo, useState } from "react";

export function Tale({ tale }) {
  const G = useMemo(tale, [tale]);
  const [{ value, done }, setStep] = useState(() => G.next());
  if (done) return value;
  return typeof value === "function" ? value((e) => setStep(G.next(e))) : value;
}
```

Now the crux here is that if you now wanted to in between these steps access state or make API calls you would have to bake the interpretation of how to do those things into the Tale component somehow. So you would basically then set out to create your own little form abstraction. It could be worth it if you want very fine grained access to the sequential rendering of the forms. And it's all based on generators, which might make it seem complicated to you, or it opens up your eyes to all the possibilities; that depends on the programmer.

There are some really good Form abstractions like Formlets that you could look into but it requires a fair bit more know-how.

Comment: Thanks for that. However, I am still confused and don't even know where to start from. I know I have to split my components and keep them dumb to make it easy to manage the state

Comment: A combination of React Portals and this Generator solution can go a long way in making complex forms easier to deal with - but everything hinges on you understanding the abstraction and why it solves a problem. I would guess that what makes your current solution tricky today is that everything is spread out and decentralized in state, different components, etc.